# Headless Forge Viewer

Tags: java, css, autodesk-forge, forge, autodesk-viewer

,Hi,

I have created an app using this HTML:
https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/tutorials/basic-viewer/

But now, underway, I want to remove the toolbar and the upper right navigation "Dice".

Which lines should I add/delete/modify in my current HTML to make my app Headless like this one:
https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/tutorials/headless/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply achieve this by using the Headless Viewer line. before you load the model.

```
///////////////USE ONLY ONE OPTION AT A TIME/////////////////////////
/////////////////////// Headless Viewer ///////////////////////////// 
//viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.Viewer3D(viewerDiv);

//////////////////Viewer with Autodesk Toolbar///////////////////////
//viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.Private.GuiViewer3D(viewerDiv);
```

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot! I wan to only show the "Home" button (navigates back to home-view). How would I do this?